# kmeans implementation with mixed variable at database level

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means, similarity, netezza

I have a table with columns of different datatypes (columns like: ProductId, Name, size, color, class, dept etc) as not all columns are numeric, how can I cluster similar products together. The data sits in Netezza and for the purpose of fast processing, I want to do it on DB side only as data volume is huge (around 2 million rows).

I tried to implement Gower's similarity in R but it takes a lot of time. Is there a UDF I can use on netezza side?

> > dput(head(prod))
>
> structure(list(Product_key = c("136220083", "134520094", "137520230", 
>   "133420231", "137420204", "136520284"), SRO_score = c(2, 2, 2,  3, 3,
>   1), PRDF_SKU_NAME = c("1496533", "1496534", "1496537",  "1496540",
>   "1496541", "1496542"), ATTRIB_VAL1 = c("Champion Canvas",  "Champion
>   Canvas", "Champion Canvas", "Champion Canvas", "Champion Canvas", 
>   "Champion Canvas"), ATTRIB_VAL2 = c("Navy Canvas", "Navy Canvas", 
>   "Red", "Red", "Red", "Red"), ATTRIB_VAL3 = c("9.5W", "10W", "7W", 
>   "8.5W", "9W", "9.5W"), ATTRIB_VAL4 = c("Keds", "Keds", "Keds", 
>   "Keds", "Keds", "Keds"), ATTRIB_VAL5 = c("VULCANIZED FOOTWEAR", 
>   "VULCANIZED FOOTWEAR", "VULCANIZED FOOTWEAR", "VULCANIZED FOOTWEAR", 
>   "VULCANIZED FOOTWEAR", "VULCANIZED FOOTWEAR"), ATTRIB_VAL6 = c("WOMENS
>   SPORT TRADITIONAL",  "WOMENS SPORT TRADITIONAL", "WOMENS SPORT
>   TRADITIONAL", "WOMENS SPORT TRADITIONAL",  "WOMENS SPORT TRADITIONAL",
>   "WOMENS SPORT TRADITIONAL"), ATTRIB_VAL7 = c("1.38 lb",  "1.38 lb",
>   "1.38 lb", "1.38 lb", "1.38 lb", "1.38 lb"), ATTRIB_VAL8 = c("SHOES
>   WOMENS SPORT",  "SHOES WOMENS SPORT", "SHOES WOMENS SPORT", "SHOES
>   WOMENS SPORT",  "SHOES WOMENS SPORT", "SHOES WOMENS SPORT"),
>   ATTRIB_VAL9 = c("WOMENS SHOES",  "WOMENS SHOES", "WOMENS SHOES",
>   "WOMENS SHOES", "WOMENS SHOES",  "WOMENS SHOES")), .Names =
>   c("Product_key", "SRO_score", "PRDF_SKU_NAME",  "ATTRIB_VAL1",
>   "ATTRIB_VAL2", "ATTRIB_VAL3", "ATTRIB_VAL4", "ATTRIB_VAL5", 
>   "ATTRIB_VAL6", "ATTRIB_VAL7", "ATTRIB_VAL8", "ATTRIB_VAL9"), row.names
>   = c(4107L,  3927L, 4260L, 3794L, 4246L, 4140L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: You should share a sample of the data. Something like `dput(head(data))`.

Comment: @tushaR updated

Answer (score 0):

You can't just use k-means with Gower similarity.

K-means needs to compute the *means*, too.

The usual choice would be PAM, but that scales horribly. You don't want to use that on your full data set.

Rather than scaling to your entire data set, use a sample first to *learn* what to do. Clustering right is *difficult*. You need to spend 90% of your time on preprocessing.

First figure out what works. Then scale. Not the other way around.

Comment: can u please elaborate a bit on PAM or guide me to some document about it? I have no idea about it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also, the custom distance metric PAM uses are Euclidean or Manhatten, none of them deal with mixed variables.

Comment: You can use PAM with Gower. Although I doubt that Gower is useful on your data either.